# Extend the PsCredential class

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'd like to extend the `PsCredential` class (in a PowerShell v4 module) to include a server name, then be able to serialize/deserialize the class using a script like [Export-PsCredential](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Export-PSCredential.ps1).  Can this (extending the class) be done easily in a PowerShell module?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can! You can [define your extension in XML, in a `.ps1xml` file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847881.aspx) and then update it with `Update-TypeData`, or even better you can specify this right in your module manifest so it gets done when the module is imported.

Perhaps the best example of this is from [Keith Hill's blog where he adds a BigEndianAddress property to `[System.Net.IPAddress]`](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/23/sorting-ipaddresses-the-powershell-way/) so that they can be easily sorted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Types> 
  <Type> 
    <Name>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</Name> 
    <Members> 
      <NoteProperty> 
        <Name>ServerName</Name> 
        <Value></Value>
      </NoteProperty> 
    </Members> 
  </Type> 
</Types>
```

(note, I haven't tested the above)

When you [create a `New-ModuleManfifest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849709.aspx) you can specify the `-TypesToProcess` parameter with the file name.

Comment: @craig I had to look up that term, but yeah it's similar to what you could do in Ruby. This method changes every instance of the class, whereas using `Add-Member` can be used to add properties and methods _to a single instance_ at run time. It's pretty nice!

Comment: Will this new property be included in the dialog that is generated by `Get-Credential`?  If not, how would you suggest populating it?

Comment: @craig no it would not be included in the dialog. Populating it should be as simple as assigning to it: `$cred.ServerName = $myServerValue` but how you prompt for that value is up to you and depends on your situation. In a function, I'd use a parameter. If I needed free-form interactive text input, `Read-Host`, if I wanted run-time interactive choice from a list, I'd use `Out-GridView -OutputMode Single`.

Comment: It would appear that the `Value` property needs to be assigned when the type is defined (i.e. in the ps1xml file).  `$cred.ServerName='foobar'` generates an error that indicates that the property is read-only.  I'll have to read more about this feature.

Comment: @craig ah I was afraid of that. I usually use it for script properties. You could do that and define a getter and setter method. The problem is that I don't know what you'd use for persistent storage in the setter. I haven't had a chance to really test that. The example of Keith Hill's blog is a script property but only uses a getter because it calculates its value from another property.

Comment: maybe it would be better to use the `Add-Member` method at run time--I'll test that.